# How to update latest image only during publishLocal

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I would like to be able to update the `latest` tag when building/publishing the image locally, but not when publishing it publicly.

I added this setting:

```
Docker / publishLocal / dockerUpdateLatest := true
```

But when running `sbt docker:publishLocal` the `latest` image is still not present.
How to achieve this?

Comment: I think you don't have to scope the setting: `dockerUpdateLatest := true` should be sufficient.

Comment: @Muki This will update the 'latest' tag on remote repository too (when running `docker:publish`). I want to update it only locally.